# v-bind:style directive not working with conditional comparison

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I can bind a class to an element in `vue` depending on a condition like so:

```
:class="i18n.global.locale == 'ar' ? 'class1': 'class2'"
```

but when I try to bind a `style` with the same condition like so:

```
:style="[i18n.global.locale == 'ar' ? { 'background': 'blue;' }: { 'background': 'red' } ]"
```

neither of the `styles` is applied to the element. Why is the `:style` directive not working?

Both directives are applied to the `container div` which envelopes all other elements.

Comment: Because you wrote invalid style, for background color you should write `backgroundColor: 'blue'`

Comment: It's not invalid with `Sass/postCsc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some research for your issue, so to resolve it you may do:

1. Check styles of element in your browser dev tools, there may be situation of overriding your bind styles from css files, for example, if you have links to css files
2. Here `{ 'background': 'blue;' }` try to delete ';', as for me it started works when i deleted.

Comment: Dang it, 2. made it work. Thank you :-)